# OpenGL textures flickering in previous location after viewport resize

Tags: c++, opengl, textures

I'm rendering a texture centered in the window using OpenGL. The texture is loaded using stb_image, and I'm using the function `glDrawElements` to render my vertices. So far everything works perfectly. When I resize the window, which was created using glfw, I also resize the viewport with a callback function that calls `glViewport` with the new size. When I do this I can see the texture rendering in its correct new location, but also flickering in its old location relative to the bottom left corner of the screen. [image: This is what the problem looks like after resizing the window.] The texture on the bottom left is flickering.

I'm relatively new to OpenGL and have basically no idea what could be causing the problem. I have searched for others with similar problems, but couldn't find anything matching my own issue.

This is the code that loads the image.

```
    glGenTextures(1, &texture);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);

glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_MIRRORED_REPEAT);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_MIRRORED_REPEAT);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);

int width, height, nrChannels;
GLubyte* data = stbi_load("texture.jpg", &width, &height, &nrChannels, 0);

if (data)
{
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, width, height, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data);
    glGenerateMipmap(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
}
else
{
    std::cout << "Failed to load image!" << std::endl;
}
stbi_image_free(data);
```

This is the resize callback.

```
    void window_size_callback(GLFWwindow* window, int width, int height)
    {
        glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
    }
```

This is the main loop:

```
shader->bind();
shader->uniformMat4("proj", proj);
shader->uniformMat4("view", view);
shader->uniformMat4("model", model);

glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);
glBindVertexArray(VAO);
glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 6, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, static_cast<GLvoid*>(0));

glfwPollEvents();
glfwSwapBuffers(window);
```

I don't want to paste all of my code for the program, since that is quite a lot. If you need some code I didn't include, just let me know.

Comment: Your issue doesn't sound related to how you load the image, rather to how your draw. Do you call glClear? Can you show that part of the code?

Comment: I added the code from the main loop. Where should I call glClear to use it correctly?

Comment: You'll need to call `glClear` whenever you begin rendering, and `glClearColor` and `glClearDepth` whenever you need to set those values (so usually just once during initialization).